# Minimal prime divisors (MinAss R)

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Hello All,is This conclusion true?

> If $(R,m)$ is a local ring and $ Min Ass R=Ass R$  then can we conclude that  $Min Ass \hat{R}=Ass \hat{R}$? ($\hat{R}$  is $m$-adic completion of $R$)

$MinAss$ means minimal primes in $Ass(R)$. "$Min Ass R = Ass R$" means that $R$ has no embedded prime ideals. In fact, if every associated prime ideal of $R$ is minimal then every associated prime ideal of $\hat{R}$ is minimal?

Comment: What does the equality "Min Ass R = Ass R" exactly mean ? 

Comment: It would be nice to have a definition of MinAss here...

Comment: MinAss means *minimal* primes in Ass(R). "Min Ass R = Ass R" means R has no embedded prime ideals.

Comment: MinAss means minimal primes in Ass(R). "Min Ass R = Ass R" means R has no embedded prime ideals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is *no* in general. In the paper *[Fibres formelles d'un anneau local noethérien](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASENS/ASENS_1970_4_3_3/ASENS_1970_4_3_3_295_0/ASENS_1970_4_3_3_295_0.pdf)* D. Ferrand and M. Raynaud give an example of a two-dimensional local domain whose $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion has embedded prime ideals. In the same paper, they mention that the answer is *yes* in certain special cases, such as, when $R$ is a quotient of a Cohen-Macaulay ring, or when $R$ is universally Japanese.

Comment: oh dear, I don't understated language of  this paper. Can you explain it more.

Comment: If by language you mean French, then you can look at the paper *Local domains with bad sets of formal prime divisors* By Brodmann and Rotthaus: http://www.sciencedirect.com.rpa.laguardia.edu:2048/science/article/pii/0021869382900461

Comment: The link I posted above doesn't seem to work. Brodmann and Rotthaus paper is published in Journal of Algebra, Volume 75, Issue 2, April 1982, Pages 386–394.