# associated prime ideal

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [minimal prime devisor(MinAss R)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89240/minimal-prime-devisorminass-r)

Hello All,is This conclusion true? 
$(R,m)$ be a local ring.if every associated prime ideal of $R$ be minimal then every associated prime ideal of $\hat{R}$ be minimal.
( $\hat{R}$ is m-adic completion of R)

Comment: Is this question substantially different from http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89240/associated-prime-ideal ?

Comment: @Anna: You can edit your previous question, instead of re-posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a response to this question in your other post. Please see [the other post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89240/associated-prime-ideal)!